# Invalid Argument in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, invalid-argument

this has baffled me for a couple of hours now. Why do i get a 'Invalid Argument' error when testing this in IE8?

```
function resizeContainer() {
    wHeight = window.innerHeight;
    $('.container').each(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            height: wHeight
        }, 400);
    });
    $('.content').each(function () {
        wHeight = window.innerHeight;
        fullPad = wHeight - $(this).height();
        if (wHeight < 750) {
            cropFactor = 1.7;
        }
        else {
            cropFactor = 2;
        }
        $(this).animate({
            paddingTop: fullPad / cropFactor
        });
    });
}
```

The exact error im getting is:

> Invalid argument.  jquery.js, line 8826 character 5

Comment: What is the jQuery version you are using? Is this the line `jQuery._data( self.elem, "fxshow" + self.prop, self.start );` ?

Comment: I'm using jQuery 1.7 from here: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js

Comment: So the line is this `fx.elem.style[ fx.prop ] = fx.now + fx.unit;` Where `element.style["paddingTop"]` is receiving invalid argument.

Comment: try adding `+'px'` to paddiTop calc

Comment: I can reproduce this in IE8 with `document.createElement("div").style.paddingTop = NaN;
//"Invalid argument."` Make sure that `fullPad/cropFactor` doesn't return `NaN`

Comment: Yeah that's about right. But... why? And what is IE's problem. Sucky browser.

Comment: @charlietfl jQuery automatically adds `"px"`.

Comment: ***ALWAYS*** use the `var` keyword when declaring variables. There is no situation where leaving off the var keyword is not wrong. With `var` you create function local variables, without `var` you create global variables. This can lead to some very "interesting" bugs, so don't do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`window.innerHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.innerHeight) is not defined prior IE, so `wHeight` is `undefined`, and `fullPad` becomes `NaN`. Try [`$(window).height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/)  instead.

Setting invalid style values in IE is one of the causes of the "Invalid argument" error.

Comment: which would explain the `NaN` which explains `document.createElement("div").style.paddingTop = NaN 
"Invalid argument."` +1.

Comment: So any ideas about what to use instead?

Comment: Waiting for a timelimit to expire! Thanks so much! 
Noobing it away ;)